# Error: cannot call methods on tabulator prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'addRow'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tabulator

I have a page with a table:

```
<table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(model => item);
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And I then initialise Tabular like so:

```
$("#myTable").tabulator({
    layout: "fitColumns",
    addRowPos: "bottom",
    columns: [
        { title: "Description", field: "Description", editor: "input" },
        { title: "Qty", field: "Quantity", sorter: "number", editor: "number", editorParams: { min: 0, step: 1, } },
        { title: "Cost", field: "Cost", sorter: "number", editor: "number", editorParams: { min: 0, step: 0.1, }, align: "right", formatterParams: { decimal: '.', thousand: '.', symbol: "R" }, bottomCalc: "sum", bottomCalcFormatter: "money", bottomCalcFormatterParams: { decimal: '.', thousand: '.', symbol: "R" } },
        { formatter: "buttonCross", width: 30, align: "center", cellClick: function (e, cell) { cell.getRow().delete(); } },
    ],
});
```

This all works pretty nicely, but I attempted to add:

```
$("#add-row").click(function () {
    $("#myTable").tabulator("addRow", {}, true);
});
```

clicking on my button to add a new row results in: Error: cannot call methods on tabulator prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'addRow'

I tried to do: `var table = $("#myTable").tabulator...` with `table.addRow({})` but then I get an error saying addRow is not a function.

Is it supposed to work like this?

Comment: Can you provide some script details to reproduce this issue? I tried using standard Tabulator and jQuery wrapper in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmvahw4n/) but the console keep throwing `$(...).tabulator is not a function`.

Comment: I followed the instructions [here](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/quickstart) and tried with the CDN first, but this also gave me `$(...).tabulator is not a function`. I ended up downloading the libraries. Using the CDN on your fiddle still gives the error (dunno if I am loading it correctly) PS. locally I am referencing tabulator.js, the jquery_wrapper.js and the bootstrap css.

Comment: The table resides in a PartialView. The Partial View has a reference to my a script file containing the initialisation code as well as the button click code. This all works fine until I try to reference the tabulator. It would appear that the DOM 'forgets' that it exists. Moving the initialisation code to the containing view AND using the tabulator 'built' callback, I managed to get it working. 

I would like to keep the initialisation code in its own script file linked to the Partial View, but unless there is a way around the DOM 'forgetting', I'll have to settle for what I got.

Answer (score 0):

That message suggests that you havnt created your Tabulator object before you have called the ***addRow*** function.

If you are new to Tabulator then i would suggest that you dont use the jQuery wrapper. that was there more for legacy reasons from the old 3.5 version.

In this case you should use the constructor:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#myTable", {
    layout: "fitColumns",
    addRowPos: "bottom",
    columns: [
        { title: "Description", field: "Description", editor: "input" },
        { title: "Qty", field: "Quantity", sorter: "number", editor: "number", editorParams: { min: 0, step: 1, } },
        { title: "Cost", field: "Cost", sorter: "number", editor: "number", editorParams: { min: 0, step: 0.1, }, align: "right", formatterParams: { decimal: '.', thousand: '.', symbol: "R" }, bottomCalc: "sum", bottomCalcFormatter: "money", bottomCalcFormatterParams: { decimal: '.', thousand: '.', symbol: "R" } },
        { formatter: "buttonCross", width: 30, align: "center", cellClick: function (e, cell) { cell.getRow().delete(); } },
    ],
});
```

And then you can add rows like this:

```
table.addRow({}, true);
```

You just need to make sure that when you assign it to the ***table*** variable it is in a scope where it can be accessed by all functions that need it

Comment: Thanks, Oli. I will look at using the constructor. Still getting to grips with how it all works (not a big front-end, jquery, js developer, so I am learning as I go on).

I have found the actual root of my problem, which I will be posting as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was initialising a Tabulator onto an existing table targetting the `<table id="myTable">` element. Although this works great initially, trying other stuff (like in my question) kept on resulting in 'Error: cannot call methods on tabulator prior to initialization'.

I ended up **scraping** the predefined `<table>` and went with initialising on `<div id="myTable">` and getting the data via ajax.

Now it all works as expected/documented. Dunno if this is a bug/supposed to work like this/my own incompetence, but at least I can move on.

Comment: Pulling in data via ajax would be a more standard way of doing it, so good approach

Comment: so it would seem... thought I could take a shortcut and define a table with data and then let tabulator convert it for me... was a bad idea. lessons learnt