# How can I make the tabulator jQuery function bindings work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

Using JQuery 3.6 and Tabulator 5.2.7

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./tabulator.min.css">
        <script src = "./jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./tabulator.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery_wrapper.js"></script>        
    </head>
```

I create some tabulator tables with the data loaded from an xml file and set up an event handler to change what data is in the table based on user input.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: xmlFileName,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            // parse the xml to build the data for tabulator
            ...
            $('#my-table').tabulator({
                data: /* that thing I parsed */,
                dataTree: true,
                columns: [
                    {title: 'Name', field: 'name', headerSort:false},
                    // etc
                ]
            });
            $('some ui thing to change table data').change(function() {
                $('#my-table').tabulator("replaceData", /* a different data set from the xml*/);
            });
        }
    });                
});
```

The initial table looks exactly as I wanted it to, but when the user clicks the thing that's supposed to load in a new data set, the table data doesn't change.
Instead I get an error:

```
jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: no such method 'replaceData' for tabulator widget instance
    at Function.error (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:2616)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.min.js:6:2067)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:3003)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:1481)
    at V.fn.<computed> [as tabulator] (jquery-ui.min.js:6:1951)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (index.html:99:48)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:43064)
    at v.handle (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:41048)
```

The tabulator documentation says:

```
Function Calls
Anywhere you see a function being called

table.getRow(1);
You can use the old method

$("#example-table").tabulator("getRow", 1);
```

So I would expect "replaceData" to work as "getRow" does in the example.  I also tried "setData" instead of "replaceData" but that had the same kind of error.
I stepped through the script in jquery_wrapper.js and it seems that in this loop:

```
 //map tabulator functions to jquery wrapper
 for(var key in Tabulator.prototype){
    if(typeof Tabulator.prototype[key] === "function" && key.charAt(0) !== "_"){
        this[key] = this.table[key].bind(this.table);
    }
 }
```

key is only 'bindModules' (twice for some reason).  I'm not sure if that's a clue or expected behavior.
Anyway... Did I miss a dependency? Is there an issue with the version of tabulator and the version of jQuery I'm using?  Do I have the syntax wrong for `$('#my-table').tabulator("replaceData",...`?

Comment: Two ideas to check: 1. Have you tried the syntax used in the Tabulator docs (ie. `new Tabulator("#my-table", {...})`  instead of `$('#my-table').tabulator({...})` ) ? 2. You mention that you create multiple tabulator tables - did you possibly (and erroneously) use the same `id` attribute for all these tables ?

Comment: The answer might be to not use the JQuery wrapper.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54627184/19300734 says
"If you are new to Tabulator then i would suggest that you dont use the jQuery wrapper. that was there more for legacy reasons from the old 3.5 version."

Comment: @collapsar #2 The divs have different ids, so that's not it.  I'll give #1 a go

Comment: Also note that The release notes for Tabulator 5.0 tell about async initialization. You have to check for the event `tableBuilt` being fired before you can safely address the tabulator table through a jQuery object (see [here](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.2/release#init) for details)

Comment: I think the question is still valid, but I was able to work around the issue by not using the jQuery binding.  Instead of "$('#my-table').tabulator({...", I used "var myTable = new Tabulator('#my-table', ..." and instead of "$('#my-table').tabulator("replaceData"," I used "myTable.replaceData(..."